# Rails: How to implement login and authentication where i have five different user models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, devise, cancancan

I'm fairly new to rails. I'm having problem on designing the model classes. So this app will be used by 5 different users(Students, Teachers, Head and Coordinator). They each are different users to login into the website and have different functionality (example: Head makes an event. Students register for an event. Coordinator sets who can be head etc). I have created all four models with USERNAME and PASSWORD on each models.I don't have user model right now because the users in this app are these 4 models. Now, while making login page, i'm having hard time on implementing the best way to authenticate the users. For example, If a Head puts its login credentials, the app should identify that user that logged in is Head. What approach will be best to encounter this?

Also, after not figuring out the way to approach this. I was thinking of using devise and CanCanCan gem. But the same promblem comes in even if i use this gems.(i maybe wrong)

Comment: Why not just one `User` model with a `role` attribute ("student", "head", etc. Because that's what your entities are, roles). Will play well with cancancan too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - my hero...

Comment: If i use one only User model, it will have a a lot of attributes in one place. I want model that does only one thing.

Comment: @Zaa: you can extract the custom attributes into "profiles". `User has_one :student_profile` and so on. This way, User is responsible for authentication and domain profiles handle domain logic.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Or, how about `User has_one :role` and `Role has_one :profile, polymorphic: true`? Then one could do some fancy delegation and stuff to determine what "type" of `User` it is and fetch the appropriate profile attributes.

Comment: @jvillian: yes, or that indeed. Possibilities are endless :)

Comment: What about the rest? Sponsors, Head, Coordinator. They still have their own attributes in their models.

Comment: What do you mean "what about the rest"? Exactly the same thing. Convert all of them into users with a role/profile.

Comment: I'm not getting your point so sorry. So you mean to say create a user model and create a role model and make many-to-many relationship? Like role will have students, teacher, cord, head with like 1,2,3,4 and make a different table to like Profiles to link them. Then how would the user find out the one logged in is student and not head. I'm sorry i am so confused.

Comment: @Zaa: Easy. You take a look at role_id of the user. It's 1 and not 3? Then they're a student and not a head.

Comment: There is a good gem for roles implementing  -https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify. And here is a convenient tutorial - https://www.nopio.com/blog/authentication-authorization-rails/

Answer (score 2):

Do not create multiple models for different kinds of users. This is almost always not what you want. Instead add a column called role of the type enum which contains all of the kinds of roles you want to add like Sergio pointed out. Your comment about having too many attributes on one model is a non issue compared to the one you are planning to create with 5 user models.

It sounds like you are possible putting too much data on the user model if that is your concern

> and have different functionality (example: Head makes an event. Students register for an event.

For this you want a permissions system such as cancancan where you can specify which features of the website each role has access to.

Comment: From all the comments that i got, i have three options that i understand. One is using STI. For example class Student< User has_one :student_info .... class Studentinfo< activeRecord belongs_to : student.                     The other one is using polymorphic.(adding type and id that saves the id of the user on his type of user table) class User < Base belongs_to :type ;polymorphic => true end class student < base has_one :user, as => :type .. end            . And the other one is to use roles for different user types. I want to mark as correct after i know what is my aproch to this problem.

Comment: and Sergio m i understanding it correctly? Sorry for bugging you guys.